# Find the treasure before Dargloc does

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story, visual

Some time ago I met an old man who handed me a scrap of paper and told me:
Dargloc - the treasure hunter is searching. You must be quicker. The key to success is to obey the rule:

> "If Dargloc rests now? You have to hurry." But do not dare to repeat yourself.

Then he disappeared while I was looking at the paper. It looked like this:

[image: Hinted Map] (Click the image to see it *improved* by @Wesley Situ)

I knew that it was a map of archipelago I visited when I was young. I got there in the evening, so I spent the night in the middle of Peaceful Island. It is the largest one and lies to the very west of the area. I woke up exactly at midnight as it was really cold. I stayed there half an hour more, then I tried to look at the Sun but it was far before dawn. I turned *a bit* right, then reached the corner of the island and there I started my journey:

> 1. I went ahead 3 steps and got to the nearest beach. I rested for 33 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 2. I turned to the direction not in west and rested in the middle of the island ahead for 52 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 3. I went away of direction not taken yet still on ground, then proceeded fouriously and rested for 51 minutes on a rock to the South as Dargloc was near.
> 4. I jumped North and East each time the bells rang last time and rested for 36 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 5. I climbed the nearest rock and faced where snow petrels breed to get to the last of the sum of the rows. Then I rested sleeping for 50 minutes, as Dargloc was nearly wrong - I was not.
> 6. I saw the Sun was rising, so I followed it 6 times. I took one step South and rested for 1 minute as Dargloc was near.
> 7. I did a mirror of my previous march. Twice. Took one step with the Wind and rested sleeping for 2 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 8. I went 5 steps diagonally and bounced once like light. I rested for 9 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 9. I got back to my starting point the same path I got here. I remembered how many places I've been to and rested for 12 minutes because Dargloc was here before me.
> 10. I moved horizontally to the very edge of the area and rested on nearest grass for 19 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 11. I turned left and reached the middle. Then turning right I saw my place to rest. I rested the hard way for 18 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 12. I went wild until I crawled on a rock the second time. I took the last step left and rested sleeping there for 9 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 13. I reached the balance between East and West and turned left to reach the almost-almost-edge. I turned left again and made two steps, where I rested for 9 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 14. I turned around and reached first grass ahead. Then, more than to left, but less than to back I made one step and rested for 12 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 15. I turned South-West and stomped on a beach. Then through water and sand I stayed away from rocks and stopped before I reached the grass. I rested there for 19 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 16. I reached two tiles from the cowboy's edge and rested there for 18 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 17. Direction on map was pointed by arrow, which head was in clock's hands. I followed it until I reached the grass. Then I jumped over water to the direction left from the two and rested sleeping there for 9 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 18. I went East and fell into water again. I moved to the row marked as digital meantime a minute ago and rested for 3 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 19. I went to more than out and made it to the beach. Sand at my right or grass to my left... I don't remember, but I jumped into water and rested there for 20 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 20. I went East and climbed on first rock from where I went 2 steps more. I went North as many times as there are my columns in "bell" counted from the middle (positive or not). I rested sleeping for 15 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 21. I went through beetles and rested for 25 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 22. I got on nearest grass and almost got to the nearest edge of horizon. Then I jumped north over two puddles and rested on nearest rock for 26 minutes as Dargloc was expecting me to fail. I did not.
> 23. I went to the direction that none of the hands pointed - to the end of the sand. I rested there for 37 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 24. I went one step closer to zero, turned right and went between 2nd grass and sand. There I rested for 38 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 25. I reached the closest rock to the West, then went 2 diagonally more as the shorter one pointed. I rested there for 37 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 26. I turned to where people's watches are late and ran like one third of the Beast. I rested there for 9 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 27. I mirrored my last march twice and rested sleeping there for 13 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 28. I let my scar feast and followed it so I reached next sand. Then I turned right and reached nearest rock ahead. I rested there for 36 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 29. I went to the last rock of the negative longitude and faced the far longer edge. I went forward and right. I rested for 52 minutes as Dargloc was not able to see the way. I was.
> 30. I turned around and saw how much water is between me and the edge. I reached half of it, then turned right and took 2 more steps. I rested there for 20 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 31. I turned to the most positive part of the map and went there until the last sand was before me. Then I took the closest slice of PI twin and rested there for 15 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 32. I went literally opposite to the last one. Except the PI. There I rested for 50 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 33. I turned in direction where I saw only water and grass - the latter I reached and went on the star to the nearest sand. Then I went one step forward and then so much South to get out of water. There I rested sleeping for 5 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 34. I went with 3, not 1 and rested for 20 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 35. I went free to near the "7". Then reached the further of middles and turned right to go and pass all the sand. After two steps to the "7" I rested for 52 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 36. I went to a rock that was like an egg, then North until I hit something in water. I jumped over a rock beginnig from noon and rested there for 36 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 37. I passed all the water of the one not found resting. I rested for 50 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 38. I moved fast ear to the second water in a row. There I rested for 33 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 39. I went forward to a point where one step sideways led me between ground twins. Between them I rested sleeping for 15 minutes as Dargloc was near.
> 40. I counted the rocks in my row and went so in direction pointed by the number of all of them. Then East to the first point where there's ground 2 the left and 2 the right. There I rested for 20 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 41. I went so far to test what only 2 tiles were left ahead and remembered the time. I rested there for 33 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 42. I jumped into water which would be pointed by the remembered time if I it was 2 hours later. I stopped after I passed a beach. I rested there for 51 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 43. I went to the beach in horizontal direction where the grass was. Then I turned right and after two steps I rested for 50 minutes as Dargloc was eager.
> 44. I proceeded to West to stop only before more than 2 waters were in front of me. I jumped into water ahead and took the nearest way to fill my hourglass. Then I took one step right and rested for 33 minutes as Dargloc was here before me.
> 45. I turned around and went to the second sand. Then colonist one step and to the nearest rock to the South. I rested there for 50 minutes as Dargloc was surprised by my affiliation. I was not.
> 46. I passed next 2 rocks to direction which the middle shows and got to the nearest beach on which I rested sleeping for 15 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 47. I did the Beast thing again and after 2 more steps I rested for 36 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 48. I turned where timely bisection would show me if read from the ends and made a step back to rest for 52 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 49. I turned to where another timely bisection pointed. One step ahead, turned a bit to right, one step more and forwards to nearest sand. I rested for 33 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 50. I jumped over nearest rock 3 times. I always splashed while landing and I did not turn without a good reason. There I rested for 50 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 51. I went 2 steps to meet a white bear, but then I turned left to take the last one. I rested for 15 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 52. I went 1 step towards the longer side's middle and turned right. Took one step ahead and rested sleeping for 20 minutes as Dargloc was somewhere.
> 53. I started counting my steps. I climbed on obstacle ahead. I turned to my left and went until I counted 6. There I rested for 36 minutes as Dargloc was wild.
> 54. I went to meet the Sun up to where I couldn't make as many steps as I counted to. There I rested for 52 minutes as Dargloc was here, looting the treasure. I did not follow him. Yet.
> 55. I went 2 the South and rested for 33 minutes as Dargloc was already gone.
> 56. I went 5 steps more and rested for 50 minutes as Dargloc was already gone.
> 57. He was gone for good so I stayed another 15 minutes to have the time to think.
> 58. After another 20 minutes of sleep everything became clear.

As I stayed there everything became clear:

> I looked at all the places where I rested and the numbered coordinates made sense.
>   I read through all the places where I rested and there the question arised - I followed the answer avoiding Dargloc.
>   From there I finally followed the signs he left throughout his search. This showed me the path.
>   As I moved along the path, at its end I knew the landtype where the treasure was hidden.
>   I ordered the places I rested chronologically and I knew that I rested timely.
>   As I visualized them I saw that I had to mark a point where 4 tiles touch each other. And I already knew which tile to choose.

As I got to the place where the treasure should be I realized that Dargloc has the treasure from the very beginning. He toyed with me to let me think I had a chance to be quicker than him.

> First part of the treasure is the half of the number of places I remembered long ago.
>   Second part of the treasure is the place the treasure was hidden.
>   Third and fourth part of the treasure take time to get, so I measured my journey and got rid of the worthless.
>   Fourth part of the treasure is the first one of the above.
>   Third part of the treasure is 1 less than a half of what was left.

The real question is: **What is the treasure?** (The reasoning is the most important part of course)

**NOTES:**

> 1. As the full solution involves a lot of work, I encourage you to post any progress you make to finally get the solution together.
> 2. I'll try to keep track of the solution progress and give hints if necessary.
> 3. If I made any mistakes (which is highly probable) let me know and I'll fix them (unless they are made on purpose)

Good luck, treasure hunters!

**EDITS:**

> 1. Updated the map image (it had wrong tile at first column and second row).
> 2. The times in the numbered directions have been updated (there was an error there). What was changed in this edit can be a hint of some sort.
> 3. The direction #5 was a copy of direction #18 by mistake. Now it is correct.
> 4. The direction #17 was changed a bit.
> 5. The direction #5's wording was not the most fortunate and is now changed.
> 6. The direction #17 was rewritten due to unfortunate wording.
> 7. The direction #18 was shifted by a minute.
> 8. The direction #31 was slightly changed to make it more precise.
> 9. The direction #26 was ambiguous, so it was changed a bit.
> 10. The direction #31 and #32 were changed from **Pie** to **PI**.
> 11. The amount of resting in direction #49 was chagned (was erred before).
> 12. The direction #31 was rewritten (the incorrect reasoning of Phlarx was fitting better than mine)
> 13. The direction #31 was mixed up - the "twin" was added.
> 14. The directions #41 and #42 were changed (another time-related issue)
> 15. The "fornt" in direction #44 was in fact a typo. It was meant to be "front".
> 16. The direction #48 and #49 changed due to incorrect time. ("On step" was a typo that should be "One step")
> 17. The direction #52 was changed (erred) from "shorter" to "longer".
> 18. The direction #53 was made clearer.
> 19. The prologue was changed a bit (by mistake the time of the journey was counted from midnight, not from half past - sorry for that).

**CLARIFICATIONS**:

1. > You can treat tiles as the same island only if they are connected by a full edge (not corner) (thanks for pointing this out by Buldelu)
2. > You will never be directed outside the area depicted by the map even for a split second by any of the clues, at any stage of the riddle.
3. > Finishing a move or even resting on a water tile is perfectly OK (assume you have a boat or something).
4. > You can move in 8 directions.
5. > Any phrase like "horizontally", "vertically", "rows" or "columns" refer to the map **after** any rotation resulting in top of the map being north. (i.e. if the map should be rotated 90 deg clockwise, columns are numbered, rows are assigned letters and horizontally means parallel to the longer edge of the map)
6. > Any word that starts with capital letter and is not leading a sentence is written that way for a reason.

**HINTS**:

1. > The first clue (first blockquote) was **solved by Wesley Situ** (see his answer or click the image of the map).
2. > All steps to solve this riddle other than executing the numbered directions depend on solving the numbered directions first.
3. > If you don't know where to start executing the numbered directions see the answer by **Buldelu** (with comments), as it **clears this part up**.
4. > Isn't the first numbered direction trying to get you out of the area of the map? (No, it is not, but it is a hint to think of it - see hint **#5**.) (**solved by Phlarx**)
5. > The journey introduction together with the first numbered direction, clarifications and Hint **#3** should tell you that the map is still not exactly what it should look like. Something which appears on every map is still missing (see hint **#4**). (**solved by Wesley Situ**).
6. > Direction#1: You are explicitly told the starting point (or at least small set of possible starting points), but the important thing here is to know where your "ahead" is exactly. (**solved by Phlarx**)
7. > None of the numbered directions ends with turning somewhere and not going at least one step in that direction (and you are always told how many steps to make).
8. > For "decoding" the output of your journey, the most important thing is the order. (**solved by Phlarx**)
9. > Even if some path looks like it is not the correct one, there might be a message hidden in it.
10. > Direction #17: The "arrow" would be even more accurate if it was 5 minutes earlier.
11. > The **PI** in direction #31 and #32 refers to something from the most distant past of this treasure hunt. Why are both letters capitalized? (**solved by Rubio** in Phlarx's answer comments)
12. > When thinking of the references of *wrong* paths in the riddle: Who would want you to take wrong paths? Some directions have different ending.
13. > About the "colonist": Read the direction aloud. Slowly.
14. > Direction #48: The word "ends" is plural, but refers to only one point in time. There are at least two elements in what clock is showing. Read them all "from their ends" and then bisect the result.
15. > There is a small set (2) of valid answers to the "question that arised" after completing the numbered directions (not taken literally). You will know which one is correct if you "avoid Dargloc".
16. > To comply with the "avoiding Dargloc" part you only have to know his name.
17. > When you follow Dargloc on his path remember that you are still on the same map.
18. > Why did he stop so many times? Maybe he needed some *rest*?
19. > Addition to hint #18: What did *you* do when you rested?
20. > "Following Dargloc": Whole path is important. Not only the final tile.
21. > "Following Dargloc" part is supposed to provide you with a landtype. The "Timely Resting" is supposed to provide you with 4 tiles. These parts can be solved independently. After both are solved you will have to merge them to get the one-tile solution.
22. > Dargloc rests on specific tiles on the map (exactly like you did before). Whole his path results in some message (which leads you to the landtype).
23. > The "I ordered the places I rested chronologically (...) as I visualized them" part means to take your resting places very "visually". Apply the "I rested timely" part in chronological order. The [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S64A.png) from Phlarx's answer should help a lot.
24. > Note that the longest resting time is 52 minutes. The number of your resting places is 58, which is more than 52, so each resting time has its unique mapping to a resting place.
25. > The "MIDDLE GRASS" message is a little unfortunate - it would be clearer if it was "MEAN GRASS". Note the "4 tiles' intersection".
26. > "Third and fourth part of the treasure take **time** to get". Definitely you should take **time** into consideration, not only number of stops. "I measured my journey and **got rid of the worthless**" - what does that mean? By the way, there is no clue about what time unit you should use; days? hours? Try to stick with the one used by the puzzle itself.
27. > Yes, the four parts of the treasure are 4 numbers that have to be translated into text which describes the treasure.
28. > The translation is not 1-A, 2-B etc. It is something more closely connected with the puzzle itself.
29. > About manipulating the time of the journey: try to see the number of minutes as just the number, or even as a string of digits without any additional meaning.

**CONCLUSIONS:**

In this section I will note some (not very inventive but still important) thoughts that may help other puzzlers make their big and complex puzzles better.

> 1. The number of directions included in this puzzle is way too large and it becomes boring after all this time.
> 2. Many directions were unclear and ambiguous. It's good to try to verify that it cannot have double meaning (if it is not intended of course).
> 3. The more separate parts (numbered directions in this case) you add, the higher the probability of making a mistake is.
> 4. If you want to create a complex and long puzzle, it is better to create many different parts than a few *monstrous* (big and scary) parts. While both solutions may require the same amount of work it is more enjoyable to switch between the parts and you can get more solvers actually involved.
> 5. Try to make the puzzle be solvable by multiple solvers at once (separate parts) so that they can share their observations and help each other (which was kind of killed in this puzzle by including too many numbered directions).
> 6. Make your puzzle well structured and readable - large blocks of (even formatted) text are hard to focus on. Use **bold font**, lists, images, tables etc. to help people see what you want to show them.
> 7. Let someone else try to solve each step of your puzzle as it is being created (with your immediate help to speed the process up) - this will enable you to spot mistakes you made before "release" to the public. I am really sorry for the number of mistakes I made during creation of this puzzle - I checked it so many times, but there were still lots of errors left unseen until someone else tried to solve this. I think this is almost impossible to create a puzzle so large only by yourself - you need a tester.

Comment: The top row appears to have writing in it where the columns have numbers. I can't make it out from the existing image, if it's at all important, could you include a zoomed image of those portions?

Comment: Every tile of color other than white if filled with that color only. Does that answer your question?

Comment: A couple quick observations: there looks to be morse code for "E" at the top of the left column and "N" at the top of the right column. Also, in the numbered directions, Dargloc is always either **n**ear, **e**ager, **s**omewhere, or **w**ild which probably correlate to N/E/S/W compass directions.

Comment: @Dan Russel: About the morse code stuff - take a look at direction in which the numbers in columns are rotated. (trying not to spoil too much)

Comment: *As you come into this puzzle, Dargloc is also born. You begin your life, and he begins a journey towards you. He moves slowly, but he never stops. Wherever you go, whatever path you take, he will follow. Never faster, never slower, always coming. You will run. He will walk. You will rest. He will not. One day, you will linger in the same place too long. You will sit too still or sleep too deep, and when, too late, you rise to go, you will notice a second shadow next to yours. Your search will then be over.*

Comment: GOLD CAR. COLD RAG. CARL GOD. CLAG ROD. OLD CRAG. LARGO CD. DRAG COL. LOG CARD. LARD COG. GLAD ROC. I dunno, it seems like Dargloc has to signify something...

Comment: isn't clarification 1 stated backwards? the natural interpretation would be to assume edge=yes, corner=maybe.  your clarification doesn't actually say corner=yes, it basically says "edge=yes (not just corner matching)" -  i believe you meant to say "corner=yes (not just edge matching)"

Comment: @Rubio I hope that now it is clear for everybody - edge=yes, corner=no.

Comment: Shouldn't the second Clarification be spoilerified?

Comment: @can-ned_food I thought the importance (and almost obviousness) of this information is pretty high, so I did not include it in a spoiler tag.

Comment: @oleslaw I agree with your points in your conclusions.  As someone who really enjoys "big puzzles" (I unfortunately have not had the opportunity to look at this one yet), you have hit the nail on the head with these points.  Also consider looking at some of the puzzles by Bmyguest and 2012rcampion.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

***[Big congrats to WesleySitu for figuring out many of the tricky bits!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44222/29647)***

#### Final answer:

> The treasure is fashionable **GOLD** located at the 9th column, **O**, and 6th row, **3**.

#### Table of contents (gosh I wish I could put in links for these):

- On the elements of the puzzle [SOLVED]

  On the geography of the area [SOLVED]

  On the starting point and other interesting locations [SOLVED]

  On the phrasing of the directions [SOLVED]

  On the moods, opinions, and locations of Dargloc [SOLVED]

  On decoding the path [SOLVED]

  On the passage of time [SOLVED by WesleySitu]

  On the treasure itself [SOLVED]

  On knowledge not yet known

  Missed details

  Acknowledgements

#### On the elements of the puzzle: [SOLVED]

> (Per OP's suggestion, these should be tackled roughly in order, after solving the numbered directions.)
>
> *I looked at all the places where I rested and the numbered coordinates made sense.* [SOLVED]
>
> > Here is a chart of the numbered coordinate for each resting place:
> >  [image: Chart of numbered coordinates vs. direction number]
> >
> > Each available row (orange lines) is rested upon a number of times equal to the value of that row. It seems like **5** has two too many, but the last two points didn't involve any movement and can plausibly be ignored, making this fine.
>
> *I read through all the places where I rested and there the question arised - I followed the answer avoiding Dargloc.* [SOLVED]
>
> > The question is, per section "On decoding the path": **Treasure is not hidden. On which tile you never rested?????** There's lots of tiles upon which we never rested. According to OP, the phrase 'avoiding Dargloc' plays into this more than just flavor. Also, according to hint #16, when avoiding Dargloc, we only need know his name. This probably means that our answer is not in columns **d**, **a**, **r**, **g**, **l**, **o**, or **c**.
> >
> > You'll note that the actual answer, given just a bit below, does not touch these columns, and also is not a tile upon which we rested.
>
> *From there I finally followed the signs he left throughout his search. This showed me the path.* [SOLVED]
>
> > The phrases pertaining to Dargloc at the end of each direction can be mapped to a series of movements. In section "On the moods, opinions, and locations of Dargloc", the meanings are worked out, and the actual path can be found in the Google Docs sheet linked from there.
>
> *As I moved along the path, at its end I knew the landtype where the treasure was hidden.* [SOLVED]
>
> > With the start point of ***space*0**, as described in section "On the moods, opinions, and locations of Dargloc", the message is *"undergrey"*, meaning the treasure is found under a grey tile. Whether 'under' means 'buried' or 'south', I'm not sure.
>
> *I ordered the places I rested chronologically and I knew that I rested timely.
>   As I visualized them I saw that I had to mark a point where 4 tiles touch each other. And I already knew which tile to choose.* [SOLVED]
>
> > This relies on section "On the passage of time", which is now solved. The message hidden in the resting durations is *"middle grass"*, which (per hint #25) seems to refer to the average of all grass tiles. Doing the math, that results in a location between rows **3** and **6**, and between columns **O** and **C**.
> >
> > The 4 tiles must be in a 2x2 arrangement, so that each tile would touch the three others at their common vertex. These four tiles, then, are **O3**, **O6**, **C3**, and **C6**. Interestingly one of those four is different from the others: **O3** is stone, matching the above *"under grey"*.
> >
> > This suggests the treasure is located at **O3**.

#### On the geography of the area: [SOLVED]

> The letters and symbols define the longitudes, with north at the right.
> The numbers define the latitudes, with west at the top.
>
> Blue tiles are water.
> Green tiles are grass.
> Grey tiles are rock.
> Brown tiles are sand.
>
> Here is my own map, rotated so that north is up. Note that the terms "row" and "column" apply after the map is rotated (per clarification #5), so columns are always north/south, and so on. There are numbers added to the map, I will talk of them in the next section.
>
>  [image: Map by Phlarx]
>
> At various points along the journey, it is possible to go along alternate routes, but these eventually hit a dead end:
>
>  [Here is a map of as far as you can get with the other possible starting point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrVBd.png) (First split, before step #1). In this layout, direction #6 leads us out of bounds, and #11 is impossible, since there is no center ahead of us.
>
>  [Here is a map of as far as you can get at the second split (step #10).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdBFy.png) The tiles unique to this path are red. Following this path, #24 is impossible, because there are no grass tiles west of the tile south of $23$.
>
>  [Here is a map of as far as you can get at the third split (step #24).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jj7A.png) The tiles unique to this path are red. Following this path, #31 is impossible, because there are no sand tiles east of $30$.
>
>  [Here is a map of as far as you can get at the fourth split (step #33).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE7eq.png) Again, the tiles that are unique to this path are red. #46 is impossible, since there are not enough rocks east of $45$.

#### On the starting point and other interesting locations: [SOLVED]

> We must determine where we start. Since we slept in the center of the largest island, we have two possibilities for this location: position **V5** or **F9**. Since the first few steps lead us 4 steps southeast from here (see next paragraphs for why), the map must be laid out in landscape, since this movement would put us out of bounds in a portrait layout. I selected **V5** as the initial location, since starting from **F9** leads to the difficulties I described next to the "other layout" map link above.
>
> The sleeping point is marked $-1$ in my map. Upon waking, we face the sunrise (east) but, of course, can't yet see the sun.
>
> We then turn slightly right (so now we're facing southeast) and take a step forward. This is the proper starting point, and is marked $0$ on my map.
>
> The tile I've marked $0$ is also marked $9$, since the ninth direction states that we've returned to our starting point. Other locations that coincide are marked similarly.
>
> I've marked all tiles, $1$ through $58$, for the locations the we rest when following the given directions.

#### On the phrasing of the directions: [SOLVED]

> For the full breakdown of the directions see [this google docs sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16iOm0nQP4iYoAD6q_bnLLjsgtGCjXrNQCMWlc3OyWc4/edit?usp=sharing), updated Feb 21 2017. Make sure you're on the "Directions" tab at the bottom. (It was much too long to include here).

#### On the moods, opinions, and locations of Dargloc: [SOLVED]

> I think the various "Dargloc was..." phrases show how Dargloc moved:
>
> - **near** or **not**: north *(near could mean northeast. Edit: nope, we don't have enough columns for that. We'd need at least 24.)*
>
>   **eager** or **expecting**: east
>
>   **somewhere** or **surprised**: south *(somewhere could mean southwest instead)*
>
>   **wild**: west
>
>   **nearly wrong**: northwest
>
>   **here**: he stays where he is, and rests, resulting in a set of positions that can be decoded in the same manner as our path (process+rules are described in the next section.) The message I get from this is *"undergrey"*, for somewhere==S, and starting on ***space*0**.
>
>   **gone**: his location is no longer important
>
> The workings-out for the message can be found in the same [google docs sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16iOm0nQP4iYoAD6q_bnLLjsgtGCjXrNQCMWlc3OyWc4/edit?usp=sharing), on the "Scratch" tab.

#### On decoding the path: [SOLVED]

> The message encoded in the path is:
>
> > ***Treasure is not hidden. On which tile you never rested?????***
>
> More details on why and how:
>
> > The first few points are (using underscores instead of spaces, since they seem to show up better):
> >
> > ```
> > Num Row Col
> >  1  10   r 
> >  2   9   r 
> >  3  12   e 
> >  4   7   t 
> >  5   6   s 
> >  6   3   u 
> >  7   4   a 
> >  8   5   e 
> >  9  12   _ 
> > 10   6   i 
> > 11   3   s 
> > 12  10   _ 
> > 13  12   o 
> > 14   9   n 
> > 15  10   t 
> > 16  10   _ 
> > 17  12   i 
> > 18   4   d 
> > 19   3   d 
> > 20   5   e 
> > 21   0   n 
> > 22   9   h 
> > 23   9   .
> > ```
> >
> > The second word looks promising! It says *"is"*! If you squint real hard (or rearrange the other words), the full message begins *"treasure is not hidden."*. I'll describe the exact method for rearranging the letters just below.
> >
> > Here is the first few points with the other layout:
> >
> > ```
> > Num Row Col
> >  1   4  w 
> >  2  10  n 
> >  3   3  o 
> >  4   5  g 
> >  5   6  r
> > ```
> >
> > This says *"wrong"* when rearranged, giving a clue that it is indeed the wrong layout. OP hints that the method by which these letters are rearranged is equal to the method for rearranging the lettering in the actual message above, and is therefore a bit of a hint. This gives extra focus to the sequence `4 6 3 10 5`, which also provides a correct subsequence to the word 'treasure' above ('asure').
> >
> > Upon determination that this sequence is not founded in mathematics, I looked to the puzzle itself to see if it was hidden there. I was expecting 'length of words in a sentence' or some such, but it's right at the top of the map, staring me in the face. (Reversed, yes, but still.) So the letters are organized in the same order as the rows, once the map is correctly rotated. Or, to state it differently, if a word has a letter from the first row it comes first. A letter in the second row comes next, if present. And so on, row-by-row down the map. If we discover a word that uses the same row twice (e.g. is longer than the number of rows), we'll cross that bridge when we get to it. My guess is that priority goes left-to-right (reading order).
> >
> > To demonstrate what we have so far more visually, here is the first few words and 'wrong' arranged by the aforementioned row numbers:
> >
> > ```
> >  7  9 12  4  6  3 10  5  0
> >           w  r  o  n  g       wrong
> >
> >  t  r  e  a  s  u  r  e       treasure
> >              i  s             is
> >     n  o           t          not
> >     h  i  d     d  e  n       hidden
> > ```
>
> All the decoded messages are as follows:
>
> > The full message on the main path is:
> > ***"Treasure is not hidden. On which tile you never rested?????"***
> >
> > The first alternate path reads *"Wrong"*.
> > The second alternate path reads *"(Treasure) hunter failed "*.
> > The third alternate path reads *"No way"*.
> > The fourth alternate path reads *"(On which) side are you?"*.

#### On the passage of time: [SOLVED by WesleySitu]

> There are 20 unique lengths for the various rests we make along the journey: 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 33, 36, 37, 38, 50, 51, 52.
>
> If we map these times to the first 20 letters of the alphabet, and apply this to the times throughout the journey, we get the following:
> `ntsorabefjieefjieckhlmpqpegotkhrdktornhknsrnrhotnrhkotnrhk`
>
> While this is almost certainly not the proper way to solve it, we can see some patterns: for example, `efjie` and `otnrhk` each repeat once.
>
> In his answer, WesleySitu noticed that these patterns actually write the letters out onto the map, where the duration of the rest maps to a marked position on the map. See his answer for details, the resultant message is *MIDDLEGRASS*.

#### On the treasure itself: [SOLVED]

> *First part of the treasure is the half of the number of places I remembered long ago.* [SOLVED]
>
> > In direction #9, we are told to remember the number of places we've been. That number is 8. Half this is 4.
>
> *Second part of the treasure is the place the treasure was hidden.* [SOLVED]
>
> > The treasure is on row **3**. This part can't be the column letter, since hint #27 says it's a number. Could also be 6, since row **3** is the sixth row down from the top.
>
> *Third and fourth part of the treasure take time to get, so I measured my journey and got rid of the worthless.* [SOLVED]
>
> > The total duration of the journey was 27 hours 40 minutes, or 1660 minutes. Per hint #29, we'll operate on the string "1660". What's the worthless thing that's referred to? Quite probably the worthless thing is just the zero digit itself, leaving "166".
>
> *Fourth part of the treasure is the first **one** of the above.* [SOLVED]
>
> > The first "one" of "166" is 1.
>
> *Third part of the treasure is 1 less than a half of what was left.* [SOLVED]
>
> > "66" remains, halved is 6, decremented is 5. (Or 33 - 1 = 32).
>
> From this, we can find the answer: [SOLVED]
>
> > We have a few number combinations, but the one that turns up actual words is 4, 6, 5, 1.
> >
> > How can we decode it? If used to index into the columns, we get the words `DRAI` or `AGRF`. Indexing into "Dargloc", we get `GOLD` or `LCOA`. If we look at the columns at these steps from our journey, we get `TUSR`. Of note, we're probably not supposed to unscramble this (since the parts are given ordinals).
> >
> > Of those options, one is an actual word: **GOLD**. Gold just so happens to be quite treasure-y.

#### Missed details:

> **On the meaning of "alternate paths" of your journey:**
> The meaning of Dargloc's state at the point you reached a "dead end" was to ensure you that this is indeed the end and no further movement is allowed along this way/branch.
>
> The first alternate path reads *"Wrong"*.
> At this point "Dargloc was **nearly wrong**".
>
> The second alternate path reads *"(Treasure) hunter failed "*.
> At this point "Dargloc was **expecting me to fail**".
>
> The third alternate path reads *"No way"*.
> At this point "Dargloc was **not able to see the way**".
>
> The fourth alternate path reads *"(On which) side are you?"*.
> At this point "Dargloc was **surprised by my affiliation**".
>
>
> **On the treasure itself:**
> Note the phrase "*As I got to the place where the treasure should be I realized that **Dargloc has the treasure** from the very beginning.*"
> Present tense is used intentionally. This was supposed to tell you that the word "Dargloc" *has* the treasure - that's why you should map numbers (four parts of the treasure) into letters from his name.

#### Acknowledgements:

> Thanks to oleslaw for making this puzzle, and
>
> Thanks to Buldelu, Wesley Situ, boboquack, Rubio, Gareth McCaughan, and anyone else who has put some of their brainpower towards solving this!

Comment: I think @WesleySitu and I agreed on the starting point, but not the direction. Perhaps I should revisit the deduction with fresh eyes. And thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Phlarx Your labels for the axes are reversed in your image.

Comment: @WesleySitu Oh shoot, you're right. I drew it the wrong way round first, then fixed the map, but not the labels.

Comment: @oleslaw (In case I change 'this' and 'other' around in the future, I'm going to call 'this' 'CCW' for being rotated $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise and 'other' 'CW' for clockwise). Regarding direction #3: I didn't know if I was supposed to take one step on land before the rest, or not (and simply face that way). Taking that first step was more convenient on the CW layout but on the CCW layout it caused me to go out of bounds -- iirc, due to direction #5. I think #5 is the biggest reason that I was having more luck with the CCW layout than the CW one. Thanks for edit #3!

Comment: @Phlarx nope, direction #6 is the step that is giving me trouble on the CW layout. Also, it seems like the direction I face at the end of direction #5 is unused, since #6 appears to fit only in one specific direction?

Comment: @oleslaw Looking at it now, in CW, direction #6 still goes OOB by one column. CCW results in an unbounceable direction #8. Hmmm. Unless a total of 6 moves are take in direction #8.....

Comment: For direction #5 see hint #7. For direction #11 I think you should take the "hard" way to rest more literally. For decoding see hint #8.

Comment: @oleslaw Positions 1-5 of that map have the letters of "wrong" (or "grown", but probably not). This must be what you were alluding to by 'the first 5 steps'. Alas, I don't have much more time to brain on this today. Perhaps something will come to me over the weekend.

Comment: it is indeed "wrong" but this should help you with the rule on how to arrange letters. There is also reference to that path in the riddle. Although your thoughts about the "clock's tick" seem reasonable, this does not refer to one of the hands.

Comment: Could Dargloc being `somewhere` mean that he was in the South-West?

Comment: @boboquack Good point. I haven't gotten to decoding that part of the puzzle, so I can't say if one makes more sense than the other.

Comment: @Phlarx The key to make the step #18 correctly is to understand what is the "digital" and the "meantime" (which is not a reference to GMT by the way).

Comment: @Phlarx I'm sorry for direction #18. Basic arithmetics so hard. See edited version of #18.

Comment: @oleslaw I know the feeling too well :) No worries

Comment: @Phlarx Great job. Your bounty is well deserved.

Comment: @oleslaw For "the shorter one", it seems to be not pointing along a diagonal (straight west). Do you mean the longer one (which points northeast)? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: @Phlarx "more" to where it points means that "the shorter one" doesn't necessarily point to the exact direction (more like general side you should turn to) you should head. Additionally it is not said that there is only one possible solution for this direction - it may lead to some alternative path. Try it as long as it makes a valid message.

Comment: @Phlarx For direction #19: "south" is indeed more than "out". I think you should know why :)

Comment: @oleslaw now that I see your comment, its obvious... :P

Comment: @Phlarx While your reasoning for the "earliest" thing seems nice, it is to be taken more literally. Consider where you would really be earliest (although maybe not very practical it is theoretically valid).

Comment: @oleslaw My other thoughts were of time zones, but I can make arguments for both east and west. (East is earlier because the sun rises there first; they do morning earlier than the west.) (West is earlier because if you were to travel instantly from, say, New York to Seattle, you'd arrive 3 hours earlier than you left, according to the local clocks.)

Comment: @Phlarx Yes, the initial concept was about the timezones - I will specify it another way as you pointed the ambiguity.

Comment: PI = Peaceful Island

Comment: @oleslaw For #29, I totally didn't notice that there was another rock. Whoops. :P

Comment: I suspect "the one not found resting" might just mean the cardinal direction not found in the word RESTING; i.e., West.

Comment: @Phlarx The "7" (as you noticed) means the row, but not a specific tile. The direction #36 you "move until exited water" while the direction states you hit something "in" the water.

Comment: @Phlarx Direction #42 is my fault again - the #41 and #42 were changed (time in them).

Comment: @Phlarx Please reconsider direction #33: You actually can go "so much South to get out of water" even if you are not in water yet, but South leads to one. And yes, it **is** one of the paths you should have followed.

Comment: @Phlarx You missed a quite important part of direction #48 (made it a *little* clearer with edit #15)

Comment: @Phlarx "Then colonist one step" is actually "Then: east 1 step", but you figured it is east anyway. The "timely bisection" (dir #48,#49) needs more literal (geometrical) approach. "Read from the ends" (dir #48) refers to one timepoint only. Direction #10 is not specified to take the closer edge (if you follow this alternate path, you should rethink the "my column" and "from middle [of what]" in direction #20).

Comment: @oleslaw even with this info, I'm struggling to coax anything different from these. (I'm reading this as finding the midpoint between the tips of the clock hands, which is slightly different from the angle bisector). If reading the end times of each step, I get NW then NE, which is identical to my results before your edit #15; if reading the start times, I get S then NW, which is identical to what I have now except #48 is in the space column, resulting in a double space. I think I'm still missing something fundamental here :P

Comment: @Phlarx About dir #48: Time you should take into consideration is the time that your watch is showing at the moment of reading the direction. Half-line bisecting an angle made of clock hands starts in the intersection point and goes (points) outwards. The trick is to get the "read from end**s**" part correctly.

Comment: @Phlarx About dir #48: I'm not sure how to state it more precisely, so it is kind of spoiled. What I meant was the 24h format (the only one used in my country). At first, read current time "from the ends" = "right to left but for hours and minutes separately" to form a different point in time. Finally bisect it to get the direction.

Comment: @Phlarx The direction #48 says "read from ends" (you got that correctly), but there is no reversing required in dir #49 (however you ended up on the correct tile). The direction #52 has an error (see edit #17), sorry. Dir #53 the "6" does not refer to the row label. Dir #50 - is it the only way you can resolve it?

Comment: This has been going on for too long =). I think this is a great puzzle, but I guess the hidden message should have been made shorter, so that there are less mini-riddles (each step) to be solved. But, thanks oleslaw for creating this puzzle!

Comment: @justhalf Yeah, I figured it out after about 10 directions that it would be enough... I will consider this next time. :)

Comment: @Phlarx Fixed direction #53. About "jumping over rocks". It is not said that you have to "turn as little as you can", but "not to turn if you don't have to". You are to find not the best solution of available ones, but any valid one. One thing (after getting the directions right, which you are really close to) I though you'd solve much earlier is to find the references to "wrong" paths in the puzzle (but it is not strictly required to get the complete solution).

Comment: @oleslaw I haven't spent a lot of time on it, but, yes, I've had the feeling that I'm missing something rather obvious there. Is it stenographic in nature? Those puzzle types are a weak point for me.

Comment: @Phlarx You may say they are steganographic (hidden in text that is visible, but it is not explicitly stated that this is the reference), but it has nothing to do with i.e. taking only some letters from some words or anything like that. The references are plain text. you only have to find them (see hint #12)

Comment: @Phlarx You are almost there - the "looned" was meant to be "looted" (not relevant enough to avoid spoiling this one) and the last horizontal direction was meant to mean the opposite to what you understood. And we're finally done with the numbered directions - I could definitely make it shorter :/

Comment: @Phlarx Having solved the numbered directions you have all the information you need to proceed to other parts of the puzzle.

Comment: @Phlarx Actually there is one mistake in your numbered directions' solution: Direction #20: "my columns" refers to the column you are standing in. You were supposed to read it: "...counted from the middle [of the "bell"] (positive or not)". Note that in the "alternative path" you are at column "L" at that moment. And one general rule: try to solve the specific parts of this puzzle in the same order they are presented in the original post.

Comment: @oleslaw I'm still not sure I understand :/ I have a question (about a different bit): the first sentence of the block quote after the numbered directions: is it solved yet? I'm guessing no.

Comment: @Phlarx Well, I know the #20 is not so clear; I'm not happy with how it is constructed, but it is a bit too late to write it from scratch - it was meant to be "-1" if you are in column "E" (1 "E" on the "negative" side of "**be**ll" and "+2" if you are in column "L" (2 "L" on the positive side of "be**ll**"). About the "...numbered coordinates made sense" it is not solved yet (you did not explain that sentence) - it is a checkpoint to verify if you've got everything right up to now - which is important to proceed.

Comment: @oleslaw Ahhhh. I was stuck thinking 'bell' was directly related to the map in some way.

Comment: @Phlarx About "answering the question that arised": your note can lead to the right answer, and yes, the "avoiding Dargloc" is more than flavor. In "As I moved along the path..." it is the path defined in previous line. I believe the times of resting are already adjusted to render a correct solution.

Comment: @Phlarx You interpreted hint #16 correctly - the tile you got there may be worth a shot. (see hints #17 and possibly #18)

Comment: @Phlarx In the "**From there** I finally followed **the signs**..." - "the signs" are the "moods (...) of Dargloc" section. "From there" is a single tile you get after solving "I followed the answer avoiding Dargloc" part. I'm not sure if you got this already.

Comment: It's always exciting to see an update to this question. =)

Comment: @Phlarx Considering the "land type" you get after "following Dargloc" I believe hint #17 and #18 should help you a lot. If the solution to that part was what you are suggesting, it would be rather ambiguous (it is not).

Comment: @justhalf Good to see there are other users involved :)

Comment: @oleslaw Don't worry, we're here... :)

Comment: @Phlarx You've got the message of the "following Dargloc" right, but there are no intermediate directions expected. Every one of them is one of the four cardinals - so your starting point should be on the tile you got from earlier step. And the "Nearly Wrong" actually denotes something else, that you missed a long time ago :)

Comment: @Phlarx See hints #25, #26, #27 and comment under Wesley Situ's answer

Comment: @Phlarx See extended hint #26

Comment: @Phlarx Maybe the "worthless" would be the "minute" (synonyms). I'm pulling up lots of blanks interpreting that phrase :P ...and if you take (630/2) - 1, you get 314, which has some resemblance to PI.

Comment: @WesleySitu and Phlarx Another mistake - I'm sorry. See edit #19. The "correct" time is half an hour more than you counted.

Comment: @Phlarx Another decent shot, but no. See the hints #28 and #29.

Comment: @Phlarx The treasure might be under 6, which makes something sensible using 4, 6, 5, 1, and "Dargloc"

Comment: Interestingly, other 4/6/5/1 words (after rearranging) look like: RAID, FRAG (those sound hostile!), COAL, and RUST (those sound like junk).  Good thing one of the set is promising :..

Comment: Huge congratulations for completing the puzzle after all this time! Another reason not to write such long puzzles... The tile where the treasure was hidden is 6th counting from map's top. I totally confused the numbered coordinates with ordinals... sorry for that. Anyway, the treasure is indeed the shiny thing you mentioned. If you don't mind I will add some edits explaining the things you missed to your answer :)

Comment: I'll give it a pass first, if you don't mind, then edit away!

Answer (score 11):

Starting from the first clue,

> "If Dargloc rests now? You have to hurry." But do not dare to repeat yourself.

I believe this will allow us to

> assign characters to the rows. The key here is 'But do not dare to repeat yourself'. If we take all unique characters (case-insensitive) in the string "If Dargloc rests now? You have to hurry.", we can fill in the sides with 21 characters.
>
>  The unique characters are "if darglocestnw?yuhv."
>
>  [image: Filled in map]

See **Phlarx's** answer for intermediate steps for what follows:

### On the passage of time

> If you take the resting intervals as the places we've rested (**n** minutes corresponds to the **nth** location we've rested), you can form letters on the map by connecting the dots.
>
>  This gives us:
>
>  33-52-51-36-50 **M**
>  1-2 **I**
>  9-12-19-18-9 **D**
>  9-12-19-18-9 **D**
>  3-20-15 **L**
>  25-26-37-38-37-9-13 **E**
>  36-52-20-15-50-5 **G**
>  20-52-36-50-33-15 **R**
>  20-33-51-50-33-50-15 **A**
>  36-52-33-50-15-20 **S**
>  36-52-33-50-15-20 **S**
>
>  **MIDDLE GRASS**
>
>  There are two grass tiles along the middle of both axes, but only one of them is adjacent to a grey tile (where the treasure should be hidden under), so I believe the grass tile is **(7, e)** and the treasure is hidden on the grey tile **(9, s)**

### On what the treasure is

> The first part is half the number of places we've remembered, which is **4**.
>  The second part is where the treasure was supposed to be, which is row **9**.
>  The third and fourth parts are measured by our journey, which would be **58** stops.
>  If we take the fourth part to be the first half **5** and the third part to be half of 8 minus 1, we get **3**.
>
>  Putting the pieces of the treasure together, we get **4-9-3-5**, which when decoded using A1Z26, gets us **DICE**!

Comment: This is exactly what the first clue was about. Can't wait to see the next steps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the times in the riddle have been changed a bit. This answer is updated to the changes.

Comment: @oleslaw Regarding the (29 Minute Hand = South?) comment, that should be the time 6:20 no? The 9 minute wait occurs after "going to the clock's tick" The times on my schedule are the times after doing the wait on each step

Comment: I actually only changed the times (and interpretation of '45 - west' to '30 - south'). I did not evaluate if it is correct reasoning. Your comment in parenthesis was applied to 17. so I left it there.

Comment: @oleslaw Got it. Just making sure that you didn't read my schedule incorrectly and created your time fix from a misinterpretation of my incorrect reasoning :P

Comment: See the clarification #3. I also made it clear that you "look at dawn" then "turn a bit right" and then "reach the corner" - this should help you get the first several steps correct.

Comment: The phrase "with the Wind", if it refers to the direction of the prevailing winds, is dependent upon the latitude in question. (Where I am, it they blow west-to-east). I suspect that this phrase may mean something else altogether, and if so, this point is moot.

Comment: @Wesley Situ You should verify the initial position and rotation (just before 1st numbered direction). If you do, I think the rest you already solved should lead you correctly (and you will award the bounty).

Comment: @Phlarx You are correct to say, that this would require some latitude/longitude specific indicators. If you can't find any - maybe it refers to something else after all.

Comment: @WesleySitu my times differ from yours from step 49 on. My step 49 ends at 22:31, 18 minutes before yours.

Comment: @Phlarx This was actually my mistake - the edit #11 (change in direction #49's rest time) fixes the issue.

Comment: @WesleySitu This is an awesome and smooth answer, it makes logical sense and generally works - however you missed some important details and due to a little unfortunate wording (by me) this is not the expected answer. I will elaborate in hints #25, #26 and #27.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I want to share my thoughts:

I tried to figure out, which island "is the largest one and lies to the very west of the area". That depends if someone counts the diagonal connections as well and which colour is counted as an "island". Here is a small map, which does not count diagonal connections, but everything except blue as "land":

```
-   -   2   -   6   -   9   9   9
-   -   2   -   6   -   9   9   9
-   -   -   6   6   -   9   9   9
6   -   -   -   6   -   -   -   -
6   6   -   -   -   1   -   3   -
6   6   6   -   -   -   -   3   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   3   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   5   -   1   -   -   -   -   -
5   5   5   -   -   1   -   -   -
-   -   5   -   1   -   1   -   1
-   -       1   -   -   -   1   -
-   4   4   -   -   -   1   -   -
-   -   4   -   4   4   -   -   -
-   -   4   -   -   4   4   -   -
-   -   -   -   3   -   -   -   1
1   -   -   -   3   -   -   -   -
-       -   -   3   -   -   -   7
9   9   9   -   -   -   7   7   7
9   9   9   -   1   -   7   7   -
9   9   9   -   -   -   -   7   -
```

Here comes a version, which counts everything except blue as "land", but includes diagonal connections as well:

```
-   -   8   -   8   -   9   9   9
-   -   8   -   8   -   9   9   9
-   -   -   8   8   -   9   9   9
6   -   -   -   8   -   -   -   -
6   6   -   -   -   8   -   3   -
6   6   6   -   -   -   -   3   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   3   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   24  -   24  -   -   -   -   -
24  24  24  -   -   24  -   -   -
-   -   24  -   24  -   24  -   24
-   -       24  -   -   -   24  -
-   24  24  -   -   -   24  -   -
-   -   24  -   24  24  -   -   -
-   -   24  -   -   24  24  -   -
-   -   -   -   24  -   -   -   1
1   -   -   -   24  -   -   -   -
-       -   -   24  -   -   -   7
9   9   9   -   -   -   7   7   7
9   9   9   -   1   -   7   7   -
9   9   9   -   -   -   -   7   -
```

The following is a version, where grey and green is land, and the other colors are "water":

```
-   -   1   -   1   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   1   -
-   -   -   1   -   -   -   -   -
2   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   3   -   1   -   -   -   -   -
-   3   3   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   1   -   1   -   1
-   -   -   1   -   -   -   1   -
-   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   2   2   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   1   -   -
-   -   -   -   1   -   -   -   1
1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   1   -   -   -   1
-   -   -   -   -   -   2   2   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

I will try different "rules" for islands later.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Don't worry, partial answers are acceptable here. Good luck with solving this!

Comment: see the clarifications no.1

Comment: @oleslaw Thanks. That makes life easier.

Comment: I think green is grass and grey is rock, so I stopped making maps with other combinations.

Comment: I think that I should clarify that blue tiles are indeed considered "water".